# Value in array equal to key or value in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I got a question to you. How can I loop through object

```
{key: 'value', key: 'value', etc}
```

another array

```
[{key:value}, {key2: value2}, etc...]
```

to check if any of the value in second array equal to key OR value in first object.

Comment: can values be arrays/object ? or just numbers/strings/booleans ?

Comment: just numbers or strings. I'm trying to compare different texts and let it know where to make a change in color to clarify difference and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first array has objects with only a `key` property

Here's a solution with a imperative approach

```js
const arrayOne = [{key: value}, {key: value},];
const arrayTwo = [{key: value}, {key2: value2}, {anotherKey: anotherValue}];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length && i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
  const arrayTwoValue = Object.values(arrayTwo[i])[0]; // This gets the value of the object, assuming the object has only one property
  if (arrayTwoValue === arrayOne[i].value || arrayTwoValue === 'key') {
    // Found a match!
  }
}
```

Comment: thats great, thank you will give it a try, but will this work if the arrays are not the same length?

Comment: Now it will, since I added a check in the `for` so the `i` doesn't go above any of the arrays length

Comment: I made a major mistake, sorry for miscommunicating, the array with keys and values I would like to loop through is actually a one big object with keys and values, so basically {key: ''value'", key: ''value'", etc..}. Sorry about, will this still apply?..

Comment: Well, you will certainly have to change the code, but not that much. Using `Object.entries(object)` you get an array in the format `[["key", value1], ["key2", value2], ...]` which you can use to loop through the object getting every key value pair in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Example your array is:
```

> array=[{key: value}, {key:value}, etc..]

```
you can get second value by this piece of code
```

> array[1].key

Comment: I'm looking to use value to check if it is equal to any key or value in the other array.
edit: also I need to loop through all of the objects.

Comment: for (let i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
                        console.log(array[i])
            }
by this way you can get all objects one by one

Comment: are you want to compare objects of single array or you want to compare an object of one array to another array?

Comment: I've made a mistake in my description, I'm comparing a value from one array to any value or key in another object

Comment: You have one array like array=[{key:2}, {key:4}, {key:2}] find which object has equal value or same value?
is this you actual question?

Comment: I have object {key: ''1", key2: ''2", etc} and an array [{key: ''1"}, {key: ''2}. How can I check if any of values in the array are equal to any keys or values in the object